# Analysis of information on ports on the Cisco switch with regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, cisco-ios

I got info about ports from cisco switchs.
I get the information with a command on the switch.

```
Show interfac status
```

And I got lines like:

```
GI1/0/1      1089.22 Office_Name      disabled      88      1000     Full
```

Or:

```
FA0/1        Big Room                 connected     120     100      Half
```

And Im trying to analyze the data with regular expression.
The end result should be:

```
Line[0] = GI1/0/1
Line[1] = 1089.22 Office_Name
Line[2] = disabled
Line[3] = 88
Line[4] = 1000
Line[5] = Full
```

What is the best way to make it?

(I tried this expression but its work very bed)

```
/\D+\d+((/\d)+(\.\d+)?)?\s(.*)\s(disabled|connected)\s(.*)\s(10|100|1000)?\s(Full|Half)/
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592),
and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166)
(ignore if you're not asking about hw).
Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @giorgiga I added the expression I made that does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `split`:

```js
let log = [
'GI1/0/1      1089.22 Office_Name      disabled      88      1000     Full',
'FA0/1        Big Room                 connected     120     100      Half'
]

let chunks = log.map(e => e.split(/\s{2,}/))

console.log(chunks)
```

If your lines are tab-separated use `split(/\t+/)`